# How do I keep Selected ListItem from ignoring other ListItems?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-3.5

When I run code the below, the If statement never resolves to 'True'. It always shows 'Assm' as the SelectedItem, even if I check all the checkboxes.

So how do I allow 'Assm' to be checked by default AND have the code-behind see that the other checkboxes are checked?

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="qualityChecks" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" TabIndex="8">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Assm" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Qual"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="PMgr"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Plant"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

If qualityChecks.SelectedItem.Text = "Qual" Then
    'Some Code
End If
```

Comment: Is the if-statement in codebehind? If so,where?

Comment: it's in codebehind, aspx.vb page, in a method that's wired to a button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectedItem of a CheckBoxList works that way.
What you want to do is iterate through the ListItems and see if they are Checked.

```
For each li as ListItem in qualitychecks.items
  if li.checked and li.text = "Qual" then       
    'some code
  end if
next
```

Comment: I get a swiggle line and a tooltip that says: 'checked' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem

Comment: I came across the answer just as you answered. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an empty CheckListBox:

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="qualityChecks" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" TabIndex="8">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and than adding the ListItems on Page_Load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim l1 As New ListItem()
    Dim l2 As New ListItem()
    Dim l3 As New ListItem()
    Dim l4 As New ListItem()
    l1.Text = "Assm"
    l2.Text = "Qual"
    l3.Text = "PMgr"
    l4.Text = "Plant"
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        l1.Selected = True
        qualityChecks.Items.Add(l1)
        qualityChecks.Items.Add(l2)
        qualityChecks.Items.Add(l3)
        qualityChecks.Items.Add(l4)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That really doesn't help with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
If qualityChecks.SelectedValue = "Qual" Then
    'Some Code
End If
```

As you have specified no value for the list items, they take the value of the `Text`